# AjaxToolkit for 3.5 not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, color-picker

I am trying to use ajaxtool kit downloaded from [here](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/43475) for colorpicker.

When i tries to use this on any of my page, it shows me an error

```
        This page is missing a HtmlHead control which is required for the CSS
 stylesheetlink that is being added. Please add <head runat="server" />.
```

What can be the reason.
I am using ToolScriptManager rather than Script Manager as said in the documentation.
I am using Asp.net 3.5 and using colorPicker control under a content page and adding ToolScript Manager in the same place.

As said by rafel

```
<head>
<title>l</title>
    <link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/style.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/chromestyle.css") %>"/>
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/JScript.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/chrome.js") %>"></script>


    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

If I adds runat in head i starts getting this error

```
    The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control 
contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
```

Comment: Can we see your header? Looks like you're missing the wonderful runat="server" directive.

Comment: @Ragael: I am using master page, and all other pages are running quite well. Whereever I adds this control. That page starts showing same error

Comment: I don't see how the error message could be any more explicit.

Comment: @Rafael: Yes you were right, after adding runat= server at head. My many other problem got resolved along with this one.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the same sequence of events that Shantanu was getting. It tells me to add the runat=server to the HEAD when I add the AJAX Control Toolkit ComboBox. So I did that and then it started saying

"The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control 
contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)." again just like in Shantanu's case.

If I am reading this correctly, is it saying I cannot use the AJAX Control Toolkit's ComboBox if I have lots of inline code in this aspx file (both in java/inline vb as well as HTML/inline vb)? I mean hey I know our aspx pages are ugly and barely hanging on, but seriously?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use <%= ResolveUrl %> when defining your javascript includes when using the Toolkit.  Add the references to the header in your code behind instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax control is trying to add its styles to the head section of your page, but cannot do that because it cannot find it. Here's how to fix this:

```
<head runat="server">
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct format is :  `<link rel="Stylesheet" href="~/style.css" type="text/css" />`

When using Ajax toolkit, don't use <%...%> in the link to external style sheet. Use above link format.