# This page is missing a HtmlHead control which is required for the CSS stylesheet link that is being added. Please add

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
This page is missing a HtmlHead control which is required for the CSS stylesheet link that is being added. Please add <head runat="server" />.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: This page is missing a HtmlHead control which is required for the CSS stylesheet link that is being added. Please add <head runat="server" />.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[NotSupportedException: This page is missing a HtmlHead control which is required for the CSS stylesheet link that is being added. Please add <head runat="server" />.]
   AjaxControlToolkit.ScriptObjectBuilder.RegisterCssReferences(Control control) in d:\E\AjaxTk-AjaxControlToolkit\Release\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ScriptObjectBuilder.cs:273
   AjaxControlToolkit.ScriptControlBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e) in d:\E\AjaxTk-AjaxControlToolkit\Release\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ScriptControlBase.cs:260
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

i am using masterpage which has head tag which contain javascript and css code in it.
it work well in local server but when file hosted live it give error

i have added runat ="server" still getting the same error

<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPageReg.master.vb" Inherits="MasterPageReg" %>

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <title>
        <asp:Literal ID="litTitle" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table width="780" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#ECE9D8">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table width="780" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="200" bgcolor="#FFFA9C">
                            <a href="default.aspx">
                                <img src="imghome/logo.jpg" width="200" height="172" title="Daptary's" border="0" /></a>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top" align="right">
                            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    </td>
                                    <td height="6">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td height="28" align="right">
                                        <a href="Default2.aspx" class="MainLink" title="Home">Home</a> <span class="MainLink">
                                        </span>&nbsp;<span class="MainLink"> </span><a href="contactus.aspx" class="MainLink"
                                            title="Contact Us"></a><span class="MainLink"></span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="2">
                                    </td>
                                    <td bgcolor="#F8C300">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                            </asp:ScriptManager>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="2" bgcolor="#F8C300">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="6">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="REDBold1">
            <td height="20" class="REDBold1 table123" style="background-image: url(imghome/title1.jpg);
                background-repeat: repeat">
                &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="lbltitle" runat="server" CssClass="REDBold1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#B12907"
                    ToolTip="Page Title"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is code of master page

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution

**1. Add a script manager**

```
<asp:ScriptManagerID="ScriptManager1"runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

**2. Add a javascript function**

```
// Write following function which calls automatically
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function show()
        {
              document.write("<head id="Head1" runat='server'></head>");
        }
</script>
```

and finally everything works fine. !!!

Answer (score 0):

You should also post the code that is causing the problem.

Have you looked at these?

[This page is missing a HtmlHead control which is required for the CSS stylesheetlink that is being added. Please add <head runat="server" />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458614/this-page-is-missing-a-htmlhead-control-which-is-required-for-the-css-stylesheet)

[AjaxToolkit for 3.5 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350572/ajaxtoolkit-for-3-5-not-working)

http://ayanigamage.blogspot.com/2012/05/i-had-web-application-which-was-using.html